# How to split data (that contains a specific character) in a cell using a specific formula?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have data in column "A" and need to split it into four columns. For example

A1 data = `1234567~00001.00~H~SX01`

I simply use the following four formulas in C1, D1, E1 and F1 respectively:

```
=LEFT(A4,7)
=MID(A4,9,8)
=MID(A4,18,1)
=MID(A4,20,8)
```

But the problem is some cells contain data that looks like: `1234567~-2.00~H~XX02`.

I would like to know the possibility of splitting data using the separator `~` that is included in the data cell.

I would like to do it without VBA. But even if you can suggest something using Excel VBA that would be fine.

Comment: Would you be willing to use, say, python?

Comment: I use that option, 
    Sheets("Formular").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="~", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Comment: Need to know a way using formulas.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use worksheet formulas you can repeated use `FIND` to get the positions of your delimiter, then plug those into `MID`:

```
=MID(MyText,1,FIND("~",MyText,1)-1)
=MID(MyText,FIND("~",MyText,1)+1,FIND("~",MyText,FIND("~",MyText,1)+1)-FIND("~",MyText,1)-1)
=MID(MyText,FIND("~",MyText,FIND("~",MyText,1)+1)+1,FIND("~",MyText,FIND("~",MyText,FIND("~",MyText,1)+1)+1)-FIND("~",MyText,FIND("~",MyText,1)+1)-1)
=MID(MyText,FIND("~",MyText,FIND("~",MyText,FIND("~",MyText,1)+1)+1)+1,LEN(MyText)-FIND("~",MyText,FIND("~",MyText,FIND("~",MyText,1)+1)+1))
```

The formulas quickly get ugly, so my first choice would be Text to Columns as @pnuts suggested.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom function like so, to split the value by your chosen delimiter into an array, and return the desired position from within that array.  This function should work with *any* delimiter you choose, and accommodates variable-length strings and sub-strings.

```
Function GetSplitValue(val As String, delimiter As String, position As Long)

Dim values

values = Split(val, delimiter)

GetSplitValue = values(position - 1)

End Function
```

In Column B:

```
=GetSplitValue(A1, "~", 1)
```

In Column C:

```
=GetSplitValue(A1, "~", 2)
```

In Column D:

```
=GetSplitValue(A1, "~", 3)
```

In Column E:

```
=GetSplitValue(A1, "~", 4)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

@pnuts has also suggested this simple macro that will perform the text-to-columns operation on entire column A:

```
Sub MyTextToColumns()
    Sheets("Formular").Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("c1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Other:=True, OtherChar:="~", _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2))
End Sub
```

Comment: Gotcha @pnuts ... my wksht formula game is weak, I just do everything in VBA usually. I'll play with it a little longer and revise.

Comment: @pnuts revised to use UDF.

Comment: That's beautiful @pnuts

Answer (score 2):

Since you want a formula solution, do this:

Select the range `C1:F1` and then click the Formula Bar at the top of Excel.

Paste the following formula into the Formula Bar:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"~",REPT(" ",99)),COLUMN(A1)*99-98,99))
```

> This is NOT an array formula.
>
> But since four cells are selected, please confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now copy those four cells down as far as needed.

Answer (score 1):

String 1:

```
=LEFT($M20,FIND("~", $M20, 1)-1)
```

String 2:

```
=LEFT(REPLACE($M20, 1, LEN($N20)+1, ""), FIND("~",REPLACE($M20, 1, LEN($N20)+1, ""), 1)-1)
```

String 3:

```
=LEFT(REPLACE($M20, 1, LEN($N20)+LEN($O20)+2, ""), FIND("~",REPLACE($M20, 1, LEN($N20)+LEN($O20)+2, ""), 1)-1)
```

String 4:

```
=REPLACE($M20, 1, LEN($N20)+LEN($O20)+LEN($P20)+3, "")
```

If you can't use UDF's for some weird reason...
Also obviously I had my original text in M20

Comment: Thank you very much for multiple techniques.